# ADB error=13, Permission denied from ADB, exists=true - Android SDK Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, permission-denied

This is a recurrent question, and it seems it has several reasons. I cannot discover mine, even after googling. Several people had answered this question, though.

The problem is that when I try to run an android project with Eclipse and ADB, I get:

```
Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/extraHD/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb":
error=13, Permission denied from '/extraHD/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb'
- exists=true
```

Some data:
1) /extraHD is my second HD, 180GB free, where I have full permissions
2) adb executable has full permission 777
3) If, after 'cd /extraHD/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools', I run any of these (no adb process running):

```
./adb 
./adb shell
./adb start-server
./adb kill-server
./adb shell kill you
./adb root
./adb remount
```

I get the very same answer:

```
bash: ./adb: Permission denied
```

And same answer when executing as root! I can create/delete files in that directory, even as a normal user...

Same problem after reinstalling ADB, both through Eclipse and zip file.

Rebooting didn't work either.

I get the same problem with /extraHD/android/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator.

Tried fsck, reinstalled Eclipse, reinstalled Tools and Platform-tools (adb in particular), reinstalled the APIs. Same thing.

Clues??

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by doing the following (mounting the sdk partition at boot time and changing permissions in fstab in order to allow writing in Windows NTFS partition):

1. Open a terminal, you can use **Ctrl+Alt+t**
2. Use 'blkid' to list the block devices and print the universally unique identifiers (UUID)

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```
3. Locate the line with the label of your SDK partition and copy the UUID value:

   /dev/sXX: LABEL="secondHD" UUID="**copy_this**" TYPE="ntfs"
4. Add a new line at the end of the fstab file so the partition will be mounted during boot:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
5. Remember to customize the "your.." values, the order it's important, fields on each line are separated by tabs or space; type man fstab for further information). Save and exit.

   UUID="yourValueCopied" "yourPartitionPath&Name"    ntfs    users,uid="YourGroup",gid="YourUserGroup",umask=0022,exec,permissions,auto        0       2
6. Restart the computer and try another time adb :)

Seems that It's a ntfs partition issue:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/207180/changing-permissions-in-fstab-in-order-to-allow-writing-in-windows-ntfs-partitio

A very good explanation of fstab-permission-masks:

http://www.omaroid.com/fstab-permission-masks-explained/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, the problem was that the ADB installation used symbolic links. Installed everything in the same partition, and didn't see the problem again.